# Curve fit and data preprocessing

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to curve fit some data over time (x = time, y = data), but I'm having some trouble figuring out the function to use and how/if I need to clean the data.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#define xdata dnd ydata

ydata = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12]
ydata_1 = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
ydata_2 = [1, 3, 7, 7, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 11, 11, 11, 12, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 16, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 26, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27]
xdata = []
for i, _ in enumerate(ydata):
    xdata.append(i+1)

x = np.array(xdata)
y = np.array(ydata)

def func(xdata, a, b, c, d):
    t = 60
    return (a * xdata * np.exp(1 - (b / (t - c)**d)))

xfine = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)


fig = plt.figure()
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax4.plot(x, y, '.')
ax4.plot(xfine, func(xfine, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3]),'r-')
ax4.set_xlabel('Time')
ax4.set_ylabel('Score')
ax4.grid('on')

plt.show()
```

As you can see, my data is very repetitive over time and the function doesn't really work as of now. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Try using `t=6` and `xfine = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)`. See if this is what you want

Comment: @Sheldore It definitely works better but the function is still wrong, No idea how I could improve the `func()`

Comment: Well, with the changes proposed by @Sheldore, I definitely get what  I would expect from a curve fit. What behavior did you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting a linear function into ydata. If you meant to fit an exponential one, try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#define xdata dnd ydata

ydata = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
        3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
        7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12]
y = np.array(ydata)
x = np.arange(1,len(y)+1,1)

def func(xdata, a, b, c):
    return (a*np.power(b, xdata)) + c
    #or return (a*np.exp(-b*xdata))

xfine = np.arange(1, len(y)+1, 0.1)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax4.plot(x, y, '.')
ax4.plot(xfine, func(xfine, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]),'r-')
ax4.set_xlabel('Time')
ax4.set_ylabel('Score')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks. I have more measurements of this data (meaning that y will be different, x will be the same), how do I combine them? I tried passing `y = [ ydata_list1 , ydata_list2] x = [ [1,2...60], [1,2...60] ] ` but it's not really working :/

Comment: Function: A special relationship where each input has a single output. So your input doesnt seem to be a function

Comment: That's right, it's not really a function, although a function should approximate the prediction well enough. I don't really know what else I can try.